# How do I resolve an Observable inside of another Observable? - rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an `Observable` in which I consume another observable, but the 2nd `Observable` I can't get to resolve.  Here is the code:

```
return Observable.fromPromise(axios(config))
        .map(res => {
            return {
                accessToken: res.data.access_token,
                refreshToken: res.data.refresh_token                
            }
        })
        .map(res => {
            return {
                me: getMe(res.accessToken),
                accessToken: res.accessToken,
                refreshToken: res.refreshToken                
            }
        })

function getMe(accessToken) {
    return Observable.fromPromise(axios.get({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
    }));
}
```

The `getMe` function returns an `Observable`, but it is never resolved.  I have tried to add a `flatMap` and a `concat`, but it still isn't resolved.  How do I get the `getMe` to resolve?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try the following (Also untested):

```
function getMe(accessToken) {
  return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios.get({
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
  }));
}    

Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios(config))
    .map((res) => {
        return {
            accessToken: res.data.access_token,
            refreshToken: res.data.refresh_token                
        }
    })
    .flatMap((res) => {
        return getMe(res.accessToken).map((res2) => {
          res.me = res2;
          return res;
        }
    })
    .subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

As mentioned in the above post, `flatMap` returns an observable. `map` is subsequently used to merge `res` with the result `res2` returned from the second promise.

Also note that `fromPromise` is a cold observable. This means that you must have a subscription to initiate things. In your case, I presume you already have something like this:

```
someFunction = () => {
  return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios(config))
     ...
     ...
}

someFunction.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Interesting proposition. Could be valuable to test it. In my opinion a possible problem is accessing `res` from the closure. I am not sure about this, but the anonymous function with `res.me` in its body, is executed/evaluated only when `getMe` emits a value, at which time I wonder if the `res` variable still holds its value. I code defensively around this by using only pure functions in connection with observables. So I am interested to know if I am being too cautious.

Comment: From a closure perspective, `res` will still hold it's value (I have used this technique before). I do concur that it's best to having a defensive style of coding and to test thoroughly.

As a side note,  if there's a second `Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios(config))` execution before `getMe()` resolves then you'll have 2 subscribe executions. This can easily be remedied by using `flatMapLatest` which will ensure that you'll always get the latest `getMe()` response with one subscribe execution.

Comment: fair enough. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Be careful in your description of `fromPromise` as a cold Observable. Though the value itself will be cached, making it appear as a cold Observable to all down stream subscribers. The `promise` itself is eager and will begin execution immediately, regardless of subscription.

Comment: Just to save everyone the quick trip to the docs that I did, flatMap was deprecated after this answer was written and renamed to mergeMap: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/flatMap. It's okay for now, but it'll be removed from RxJS in version 8.

Answer (score 2):

As @user3743222 pointed out, an `Observable` does not `resolve` in the sense that a `Promise` does. If you want the value you of the `getMe` method you will need to subscribe to the `Observable` returned by it.

```
return Observable.fromPromise(axios(config))
        .map(res => {
            return {
                accessToken: res.data.access_token,
                refreshToken: res.data.refresh_token                
            }
        })
        .flatMap(function(tokens) {

          //FlatMap can implicitly accept a Promise return, so I showed that here
          //for brevity
          return axios.get({url : 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me'});
        },

        //The second method gives you both the item passed into the first function
        //paired with every item emitted from the returned Observable`
        //i.e. axios.get(...)
        function(tokens, response) {
          return {
            accessToken: tokens.accessToken,
            refreshToken: tokens.accessToken,
            //Here response is a value not an Observable
            me: response
          };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to find below (UNTESTED!!). Some explanations :

- the observable returned by `getMe` is not flattened ('resolve' belong to the world of promises) because the `map` operator does not flatten observables. `flatMap` do, but you need to use it in the form `source.flatMap(function(x){return observable})` and here what you return is a `POJO` not a `Rx.Observable`.
- So, to flatten the `getMe` we use a `flatMap`.
- To add back the missing fields (`accessToken` and `refreshToken`) we use `withLatestFrom` on the observable who emitted the `res` object (`res$`).
- We use `share` as we subscribe twice to `res$`, and we want all subscribers to see the same values.

  ```
  var res$ = Observable
    .fromPromise(axios(config))
    .map(function ( res ) {
         return {
           accessToken  : res.data.access_token,
           refreshToken : res.data.refresh_token
         }
       })
    .share();
  var getMe$ = res$.flatMap(function ( res ) {return getMe(res.accessToken)});
  var finalRes$ = getMe$.withLatestFrom(res$, function ( getMe, res ) {
  return {
     me           : getMe,
     accessToken  : res.accessToken,
     refreshToken : res.refreshToken
   }
  });

  function getMe ( accessToken ) {
    return Observable.fromPromise(axios.get({url : 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me'}));
  }
  ```

Comment: POJO = Plain Old Javascript Object

Comment: Thank you for the help, but this seems more convoluted than using `Promises`.  There has to be a more concise way.

Comment: Sure let's see what others come up with. Question : why don't you use promises, and then convert to observable when you have the result you want? `Rx.Observable.fromPromise` does that, that way you have the best of both worlds.

Comment: POJO has been taken loooong looong ago by JAVA => Plain Old Java Object. Javascript was not OOP back then ....